# wscript.exe and Task Manager

Tags: wsh, taskmanager

Is there any way to start `foobar.js` WSH-script in order that standard Task Manager will display a script process name as `foobar.something` and not as "wscript.exe"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard *Task Manager*? not that I know of.
But if you are ready to switch to [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) instead,
selecting a *Command Line* display column will clearly show `foobar.js` .

Answer (score 0):

No. Task Manager shows actual process objects.  A .js file will never be a process object.

The WScript object managed by the windows scripting host does not appear to expose the application title either.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be surprised if you can change the name associated with a process in task manager. But if your goal is to identify the process programatically, you can use the process ID (PID). You can add a column to the task manager view that will display this information or you can get the ID of processed spawned from within WSH using the following property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x78640t0(VS.85).aspx